# Code128/EAN128 barcode component for Fast Report?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, barcode, fastreport, code128

During a migration of reports which contain EAN128 / Code128 barcodes to Fast Report I found that Fast Report does not use the correct symbology. The lines of a Code128 barcode are very wide so that they are perfect for long distance scanning in a warehouse. I reported it, but only received a recommendation for a third-party barcode library. This one seems to use the correct symbology but it is still in development (for many months now) and not working with Fast Report in Delphi 2009 yet.

Are there other Code128 / EAN128 barcode libraries available for Fast Report?

Code128 barcode example:

[image]

**Update**: one month later. In the meantime we have received source code from the third-party barcode developer - but it is the same buggy code we received in October 2009. So our projectas are stuck with
* Fast Reports wrong Code128 implementation
* incomplete and buggy third party library
* too little time to implement this ourself, so we still use the Delphi 7 printing system based on QuickReport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new release 4.9 of Fast Report solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the dlSoft component [dBarcode.NET](http://www.dlsoft.com/developers/dbcdotnet.htm).

It is a standalone component, and as such, you would need to generate the code and embed it in the report.

Comment: it is a Delphi Win32 (not .NET) application and I would like to keep dependencies minimal

Answer (score 0):

I use these http://psoft.sk/

Comment: This is the third party library which does not work with Delphi 2009 - the latest 'beta' version did not display the database values in the barcode.

Comment: Their 'news' page says their latest version is compatible with 2009 & 2010.  I don't use 9/10 so I can't give first hand experience, but I've used their components for over 6 years without any problems.

Comment: They have not yet released the Delphi 2009 version for Fast Report - we have been very happy users of the Delphi 7 version for Quick Report for many years too. So let's see when it is ready...

Comment: Um, stay away from this vendor. Support is non-existant, and some code doesn't even compile in the latest version. I've asked for a refund (they sell through Digital River.) Let's see what happens.